# Android SDK and API

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

I'm very new to Android programming, please allow me ask a very basic question. My question: what is Android SDK version and how it's different from API level?

If uses-sdk in AndroidManifest.xml says "android:minSdkVersion="19" ", does it mean minimum required sdk would be Kitkat 4.4, API level 19?
Thanks
-S

Comment: SDK version = API level. see https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API Level is an integer value that uniquely identifies the framework API revision offered by a version of the Android platform.

The Android platform provides a framework API that applications can use to interact with the underlying Android system. The framework API consists of:

A core set of packages and classes

A set of XML elements and attributes for declaring a manifest file

A set of XML elements and attributes for declaring and accessing resources

A set of Intents

A set of permissions that applications can request, as well as permission
 enforcements included in the system

Each Android version have its own API.

Answering your question, yes with "android:minSdkVersion="19" the minimum android version for app would be KitKat 4.4

Answer (score 2):

> what is Android SDK version and how it's different from API level?

SDK Versions and API levels as concepts are the same thing.

However the Android SDK version you compile your app with is independent from of what API level your app is running on.

> If uses-sdk in AndroidManifest.xml says "android:minSdkVersion="19" ", does it mean minimum required sdk would be Kitkat 4.4 , API level 19? Thanks -S

That means that the earliest version of Android your app will be installed on via the Google Play Store will be Android 4.4 (API 19) devices.

I'd strongly suggest reading the [Picking your compileSdkVersion, minSdkVersion, and targetSdkVersion blog post](https://medium.com/google-developers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd), which goes into detail on each of these, how they relate, and what you should use.

The basic requirement is

> minSdkVersion <= targetSdkVersion <= compileSdkVersion

But the ideal situation for apps, particularly new apps, it should be

> minSdkVersion (lowest possible) <= 
>       targetSdkVersion == compileSdkVersion (latest SDK)